# Grep n'th element

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, cut

I have a log file in which i need to grep some specific fields.

The log file uses spaces for separating the elements in lines, but a line may also contain a sentence with quotation marks. I need to grep the n'th element.

A line in the file could look like this:

```
2018-05-01 12:05:16 9 10.10.10.20 ab bc - - foobar - "bar foo" - "barbar foo" cd ed
2018-05-01 12:05:16 9 10.10.20.20 ab bc - - foobar - "barfoo" abc "barbar foo" cd ed
```

I would like to grep the 13th element, for 1st line it is "barbar foo" and the 2nd line it is "abc foo"

So a

```
cut -d " " -f 13
```

wont do it, as 1st line 11th element has "bar foo" and the 2nd line 11th element is "barfoo"

Hope this makes sense!
All help is appreciated

Comment: _for_- -_the 2nd line it is "abc foo"_ No, it's not.

Comment: Well true, it is also "barbar foo" for the 2nd line :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^ ]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{print $13}' file
"barbar foo"
"barbar foo"
```

More on [FPAT here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html).

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'my @p = /"[^"]*"|[^\s"]\S*/g; say $p[12]' file
"barbar foo"
"barbar foo"
```

If the quoted sections can contain escaped quotes (`\"`), then you need

```
$ perl -nE 'my @p = /"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[^\s"]\S*/g; say $p[12]'
```

Comment: Usually perl compared to awk looks greek to me but in this particular case they look equally barf. :D ++

Comment: @JamesBrown Well, all the gnarly bits are in the regex. :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point. That was a brain fart; I meant `[^\s"]`.

Comment: Well this also does the trick! thanks a lot! 
How ever i prefer awk

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`

```
grep -Po '^([^" ]+ |"[^"]*" ){12}\K([^" ]+|"[^"]*")' file
```

or more portably with `sed`

```
sed -En 's/^([^" ]+ |"[^"]*" ){12}([^" ]+|"[^"]*").*$/\2/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Prints fourth and third fields from the end.

```
awk '{print $(NF-3),$(NF-2)}' file
"barbar foo"
"barbar foo"
```